# Firefox question: Is it possible to create an html iframe which loads a document from my extension using the chrome://?

Tags: url, iframe, firefox-addon

I was wondering if it is possible to create an iframe whithin a HTML document pointing to a XUL document whithin my firefox extension such like:

```
<iframe src="chrome://myextension/content/document.xul"/>
```

I am currently getting security errors when trying to do this. I've already tried the ***contentaccessible=yes*** flag in my chrome.manifest but it didn't work.

Is there any workaround to get this working?

Thanks.

Comment: It should be noted, http:// or untrusted data url here can be security vulnerability in Chrome-privilege windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, web pages are generally not allowed to load chrome documents. `contentaccessible=yes` refers to images and scripts that are less regulated security-wise (they can also be used across domains). However, your extension has permission to load chrome documents - even into a content page. So doing something like this from your extension will work:

```
window.content.frames[0].location.href = "chrome://myextension/content/document.xul";
```

Not sure whether this will help you, depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: All I'm trying to achieve is to load some XUL documents contained in my extension directly into my website. I've already tried remote XUL but I'm getting lots of security errors so i guess that's not a choice. Do you think firing custom events from the webpage and catching them in the extension would be enough to access my dynamically created iframes and change their src attribute?

Comment: @santiageitorx: Yes, that will work - and indeed that's the recommended approach to communication between websites and extensions. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages

Comment: Ok thanks once again Wladimir, you have been very helpful. I will try it right now.

Comment: I've just tried it. The communication works fine, the event is received by the extension and I can change the iframe's src attribute to any url I like, but it is still not loading chrome://myextension/content/document.xul or any other xul document whithin my extension; It just does nothing and I get no errors in the js error console. `evt.target.parentNode.setAttribute('src', 'chrome://myextension/content/document.xul');` doesn't change anything but `evt.target.parentNode.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.google.com');` works fine. Any advice?

Comment: Setting `src` attribute loads the frame asynchronously - you should set `location.href` as in my example.